# Random number seed targeting the same version of the .NET framework

Tags: c#, random

Does every CPU return the same random sequence based on the same seed if my application targets .NET framework 3.5?  I am checking if you get the same result as me. I am also hoping that everyone who I distribute my application to will get the same result. Thanks!

```
Random a = new Random(44448);
int i1 = a.Next(65, 90);
MessageBox.Show(i1.ToString());
```

Comment: Everytime you use a Random object with the same seed, you'll get the same random sequence.

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: If you *really* want to know... `77`

Comment: More of a forum post for fun. Better question would have been, does every CPU return the same random sequence based on the same seed.

Comment: for an explanation of why you always get the same result google pseudorandom numbers

Comment: Guys, I think you're misunderstanding what he's trying to ask.

Comment: @ZNK-M - that is not necessarily correct. Different versions of the .NET framework will result in different sets of values because the algorithm for Random is an implementation detail subject to change in any version.

Comment: I also got 77. This is great news! Thanks guys! But what about different .net frame work versions?

Comment: @JohnRasch I was assuming he is testing twice the program with the same version of the framework :)

Comment: @NewsReader Re-ask your question along the lines of what I mentioned earlier. Including the variables, like framework version. Hopefully you're not writing a gambling app for my local casino...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a specific framework version your program should give the same result each time you run it, because of the fixed seed.

**But it can give different results on different versions of the .NET framework.**

For example, on .NET 4.0 I get `77`. But putting the code into [ideone](http://ideone.com/2HxoG) (which uses Mono) gives `67`.

The reason for this difference is because the precise algorithm used by `Random` is not part of the specification. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) has this information about the algorithm:

> The **current** implementation of the Random class is based on a modified version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.
>
> ...
>
> The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class is **not guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework**. As a result, your application code should not assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.

Emphasis mine. There are no guarantees that future implementations will use the same algorithm.

Comment: There is no "mono" tag in the OP question.

Comment: @Oscar whether or not it was tagged `mono` seems irrelevant to me — the point is that different (current or future) implementations may return different results.