# Random number seed targeting the same version of the .NET framework

Tags: c#, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random number seed targeting the same version of the .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619074/random-number-seed-targeting-the-same-version-of-the-net-framework)

Does every CPU return the same random sequence based on the same seed if my application targets .NET framework 3.5? I am wondering if you get the same result as me. I am also hoping that everyone who I distribute my application to will get the same result also. Thanks!

```
Random a = new Random(44448); 
int i1 = a.Next(65, 90); 
MessageBox.Show(i1.ToString());
```

Comment: Then it wouldn't be random, would it?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on this returning the same value - even on your own system - even though it might do at the moment. If Microsoft release a patch to .NET that changes the behaviour then your code will break and you'll have a hard time tracking it down,

Comment: I think we should just reopen the other question with the edits. Mark had a thoughtful answer on it.

Comment: Also, please don't repost your question - edit the original.

Comment: @ChrisF he did, it needs to be reopened.

Comment: @ChrisF Actually, it's specifically intended to get the same results when using the same seed.  It's documented behavior.

Comment: @Servy - That is true - I'd forgotten about that. However, it's still bad design for a production environment.

Comment: @ChrisF depends on the use-case, if you want an essentially infinite sequence of random numbers that is consistent across all installations this is certainly an easy way to do that

Comment: @Servy that may be true, but we've shown that on Mono it returns a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the same seed you will get the same random numbers in the same order, every time.  That is by design.  Example of when you would want to do this:

- When testing a program you can use a fixed seed so that you get the same results.
- If you log the seed used in your program and you have a problem then you can determine the resulting random numbers so you can try to reproduce the bug.
- If you want to measure performance you can use a fixed seed so that you don't get different data on different runs.

By default (meaning when you specify no seed) the the system time will be used.  The general idea here is that you take a single "random" number and, using that, you can make lots more "random" numbers. If you take the current time down to some really, really small level of precision then it really is effectively random.  Most of the time this default behavior will be acceptable for you, as long as you make sure not to create new instance of `Random` too close together (so that they don't have the same seed).  You could also generate a random number through a more secure algorithm and pass that in as the seed.  (One example I've seen people do is to create a new GUID and pass it in as the seed.  It's actually a decent idea.)