# how can I get same random number after restart application in c#

Tags: random

I would like to get same random number after restart the code.

İs is possible because system clock is changing while I restart the application.

1-start the application
2-result of the random number( example array size 10 and every numbers are same)
3-close the application
4-Don't change any code
5-Start application again
6-result of the random number( example array size 10 and every numbers are same)

in second and sixth step ı would like to get same number? how can ı get it. is it possible?

Comment: You could save the random number to a file and then have the code read it from the file in step 6.

Comment: no just run the program.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619074/random-number-seed-targeting-the-same-version-of-the-net-framework.

Comment: ı don t have any idea about multiple CPU behaviours.